# c++ - Valgrind on codeblocks (linux)

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory-leaks, codeblocks

I already use the `Valgrind` in small programs to check `memorys leaks` and its work good.

Now i have a big program with many class and `.cpp` and `.h` files and i'm trying to use `Valgrind` to check the `memory leak` because i use a lot of pointers, memory, etc.

I'm using `linux` and `codeblocks 16.01` with `gcc` and i trying to run the `Valgrind` directly in `codeblocks` but i'm getting the follow error:

```
 --------------- Application output --------------
valgrind: /myPathToTheProject/ValgrindOut.xml: No such file or directory
```

If i test with a small project with only a `.cpp` file and main it works good and the `Valgrind` generate the `ValgrindOut.xml`. In this big project i always getting this error. Someone have some idea what is wrong? or other way or tool to test `memory leak`?

EDIT - LEAK SUMMARY after running Valgrind

```
Leak summary:

definitely lost: 673 bytes in 6 blocks.
   indirectly lost: 89,128 bytes in 68 blocks.
     possibly lost: 232 bytes in 2 blocks.
   still reachable: 80,944 bytes in 6 blocks.
        suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
```

Comment: Please exaplain how exactly do you run it and where are you getting this error?

Comment: I'm running directly in codeblocks. Top menu bar -> valgrind -> run memcheck and error appear in codeblocks in valgrind 'console' output

Comment: can you just run it from linux shell instead? this seems like a codelocks (whatever it is)  issue.

Comment: I never run Valgrind in linux shell. Do you know how to run?

Comment: Is It supposed to there are already a .xml file to write output?I'm just guessing,I don't use valgrind in any IDE. I always run valgrind in shell.

Comment: @RMRMaster to run valgrind from a shell you literally just type "valgrind <executable>" where <executable> is the name of your executable. It's that simple.

Comment: @RMRMaster valgrind  --leak-check=full  --show-leak-kinds=all ./app

Comment: Thanks for your replys. I have a doubts. When i run the valgrind in linux shell like you did to do the valgrind check all class's? because my program is a little big (it is a rest api) so many of class are called when i do some request.. so in this case when i run the program in the valgrind we check all class's regardless of whether or not they are being called?

Comment: If i terminate the program, the valgrind show in shell the result test. 

see the edit please and check the LEAK SUMMARY

Whats its mean? can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how to run valgrind directly from codeblocks. I suggest you build your project using codeblocks. While executing, use valgrind as per below command.

**Command**

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --log-file=leak.txt ./myexecutable <my command line arguments>
```

**Example**

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --log-file=leak.txt ./myexecutable -i 192.168.1.10 -p 5000
```

This way you can generate valgrind output file, that is leak.txt that contains memory leaks etc.

Comment: Thanks. Its real helps me. For example what its mean:

112 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 25 of 38? 

I have a lot of message very equal to that.

Comment: These are memory leaks. You have allocated some memory, but never freed. The pointer that points to allocated memory is modified / over-written, hence you will never be able to free it during lifetime of program execution. Since I do not have source code, it is very difficult to tell what is exactly wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I have some problems with memory leak beacause of this (my new post)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45441303/c-mysql-connector